# How to sort two lists according to order in one of them?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have two arrays of hashes sorted by `:id`:

```
tweets = [{ id: 1, foo: 3, type: 'tweet' },
          { id: 2, foo: 5, type: 'tweet' },
          { id: 3, foo: 9, type: 'tweet' }]

events = [{ id: 4, foo: 6, type: 'event' },
          { id: 5, foo: 1, type: 'event' }]
```

I merged them to get the result hash `all`. I want to sort it by the order of `:id`:

```
[{:id=>1, :foo=>3, :type=>"tweet"},
    {:id=>2, :foo=>5, :type=>"tweet"},
    {:id=>4, :foo=>6, :type=>"event"},
    {:id=>5, :foo=>1, :type=>"event"},
    {:id=>3, :foo=>9, :type=>"tweet"}]
```

Can you help me achieve that? If I do:

```
all.sort_by! { |ob| ob[:foo] }
```

I receive:

```
[{:id=>5, :foo=>1, :type=>"event"},
    {:id=>1, :foo=>3, :type=>"tweet"},
    {:id=>2, :foo=>5, :type=>"tweet"},
    {:id=>4, :foo=>6, :type=>"event"},
    {:id=>3, :foo=>9, :type=>"tweet"}]
```

Comment: _But I want other result - according to order by id of events_:
what do you mean by that?

Comment: @YanisVieilly I want lossless insert sorted array in other array. It's should sort by `foo` field without losing previous order by **id** (4,5)

Comment: I am still not quite sure about what you want to do exactly, but if you want to sort by multiple values (in your case by `id`, then by `foo`) you can do the following: `all.sort_by! { |ob| [ob[:id], ob[:foo]] }`

Comment: @YanisVieilly if i do like that - it will sort by **id** because Id - is unique value so it will sort without using foo field and result will be another, try

Comment: Hashes are random access structures and sorting does nothing useful. Why do you want to sort one? Why can't you extract the keys and sort those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Array
  def reverse_each_with_index(&block)
    (0...length).reverse_each do |i|
      block.call self[i], i
    end
  end
end

def sort_by_foo(events:, tweets:)
  result = events.clone
  tweets.reverse_each do |twt|
    inserted = false
    result.reverse_each_with_index do |evn, i|
      if twt[:foo] <= evn[:foo] && evn[:type] == 'event'
        result.insert(i + 1, twt)
        inserted = true
        break
      end
    end
    result.unshift(twt) unless inserted
  end
  result
end
```